# Using $ sign with jQuery gives error when including readyselector plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a rails application and is using [readyselector](https://github.com/Verba/jquery-readyselector/blob/master/jquery.readyselector.js)
plugin to include page specific javascript.

Here is the readyselector code.

```
(function ($) {
  var ready = $.fn.ready;
  $.fn.ready = function (fn) {
    if (this.context === undefined) {
      // The $().ready(fn) case.
      ready(fn);
    } else if (this.selector) {
      ready($.proxy(function(){
        $(this.selector, this.context).each(fn);
      }, this));
    } else {
      ready($.proxy(function(){
        $(this).each(fn);
      }, this));
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Following is the order of inclusion in `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require plugins/readyselector
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
---------- other files
--------
```

One of my javascript file starts like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({ height: 0, width: 0, 'overflow': 'hidden' });
....
....
});
```

I'm getting an error saying `$().css` is not a function. But if i use `jQuery` instead of `$` the code will work fine.

When i remove the plugin there are no errors too.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: No valid reason that code shown would throw that error

Comment: When i remove the plugin the code is working fine.

Comment: Are you using `jQuery.noConflict()` and therefore that's why you need to pass `$` into `ready`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the $ parameter to your document ready:

The value of this parameter is 0 and no more a function (shorter name for jQuery)!

You may debug and see it by yourself.

```
 (function ($) {
        var ready = $.fn.ready;
        $.fn.ready = function (fn) {
            if (this.context === undefined) {
                // The $().ready(fn) case.
                ready(fn);
            } else if (this.selector) {
                ready($.proxy(function(){
                    $(this.selector, this.context).each(fn);
                }, this));
            } else {
                ready($.proxy(function(){
                    $(this).each(fn);
                }, this));
            }
        }
    })(jQuery);


    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({ height: 0, width: 0, 'overflow': 'hidden' });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

plugin is not equipped to pass `$` argument into `ready` the way default allows

Can get around this by wrapping your code in IIFE the same way plugin is done

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({ height: 0, width: 0, 'overflow': 'hidden' });    
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Or use a simpler method instead of plugin:

```
(function ($) {      
  $.fn.exists = function (fn) {
    if(this.length){
        fn();
    }
  }
})(jQuery);

$('.someClass').exists(function(){    
  var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({ height: 0, width: 0, 'overflow': 'hidden' });
});
```

Personally I would not want to extend `$.fn.ready` for undocumented use that could be confusing in code base in the future. Most jQuery familar developers would see `$('.someClass').ready(func..` and say that does nothing and might be inclined to remove it

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uza8jzw1/)**</kbd>